# how to display a document in my aspx page

Tags: asp.net

My apsx page basically displays the product description.

A user designs his own classified add and the description is displayed on an aspx page as he has designed it.  To make the description more elaborate and instead of designing more components I thought that user should design an additional file (catalog of his product) and upload that at the time of designing the advert.

Now what format of file should I allow the user to create a catalog and how to show the file in the same description page?  Can I use update panel? iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user to upload PDF file and use `iframe` to show it.
[Basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvvm2/1/)

PDF is very popular these days and most people have reader installed including plugins for their browser.

Edit: also possible to ask them for either PDF or Word file (.doc) and in case of Word document convert it to PDF [on the fly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/f8989c05-d04a-4b4a-be0f-fc0055691de7).

Comment: pdf reader is very popular but most people dont know how to create pdf document.